# Write to s3 express one zone bucket using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Could anyone let me know what am I missing here?

```
df.write.csv("s3://express-demo--use1-az4--x-s3/output", mode="overwrite")
```

> error : java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied

```
df.write.csv("s3a://express-demo--use1-az4--x-s3/output", mode="overwrite")
```

> error : py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.csv.
> : org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSBadRequestException: getFileStatus on s3a://express-demo--use1-az4--x-s3/output: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The authorization header is malformed; incorrect service "s3express". This endpoint belongs to "s3". (Service: S3, Status Code: 400

Comment: Might help: [Upload data to Amazon S3 Express One Zone - Amazon EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-express-one-zone.html)